# What is a better way to prevent over-discharge in this low current circuit?

Tags: lithium-ion, protection, circuit-protection, undervoltage

I made a nightlight and was very happy with the dim yet usable output and runtime (months), but my assumptions about battery safety were wrong. I expected the LDO 3.3 V regulator to stop output when the source voltage dipped below 3.3 V, and that it would not draw much current in that case. I must have been wrong, since the 18650 lithium ion cell was irredeemably dead after a couple months. The circuit is below.

[image: Nightlight 18650 LED circuit]

(Note: the output would be more efficient with two LEDs and a changed resistance to reduce the current as needed. At tiny currents like this, even a white LED does not have the expected large voltage drop.)

How could I better protect the battery from over-discharge? Could I use an additional regulator (3 V), a comparator, and a MOSFET so the comparator switches off the MOSFET if the battery's output voltage becomes less than 3 V? Even if it works, finding low power versions of these chips might be hard (or expensive). Is there a better way to cause the circuit to turn off instead of draining the battery? I assume a dedicated battery protection IC would be best, but most seem to come in a package that I won't be able to solder at home.

Comment: You can find a battery protection *module* that is solderable.

Comment: Why not just find an LDO with an acceptable drop-out voltage?

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't care about the drop-out as long as it's positive. Is it atypical that the battery was drained below ~3.4 V in this case? I thought the regulator would stop drawing current, but it seems not to have.

Comment: The 2950 you use doesn't drop out (stop regulating) until the input voltage gets very low, something like 300mV. If you choose an LDO with a drop out voltage closer to 3.4V it won't continue to discharge the battery below that value because it turns voltage regulation off. A battery protection circuit would be better, but if you use the right parts it doesn't need to be complicated.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks! It seems I always misunderstood LDOs: I thought the low "drop out" referred to the voltage drop (and hence, there was an important spec I was ignoring). I will look for one with a 3.1-3.3 V drop-out. Do you want to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @RonBeyer An internet search leads me to believe the dropout voltage is what I originally thought: the voltage drop that occurs from input to output. Are you sure there are LDOs which will stop conducting when the input voltage drops too far below the expected output?

Comment: Some LDO's use that metric for shutdown, yes, but looking at the [datasheet for the 2950](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/fdscontent/uscompanion/us/pdf/microcircuits/students/zandr/LP2950.pdf), it doesn't look to be the case for this chip. Take a look at page 12, the "Shutdown Threshold Voltage", that says that the regulator won't be off (at room temp) until about 1.3V. Page 8 has the dropout characteristics for a 5V output which you may be able to translate to 3.3V.